# jQuery-ui slide without adjusting width of existing elements

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, slide

I am trying to slide out a name on a mouseover event in a `twitter-bootstrap` navbar.

My code slides the name out, but during the transition the positioning of the elements go haywire.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/362cmyb8/) showing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/362cmyb8/2/
I have added some css so it should be ok now.

To keep text in one line I added this:

```
#name {display:inline-block}
```

And for the parent element to not get bigger in height I added this:

```
.name {overflow:hidden}
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a bit, but is there a way to make it more controlled so that constant mouse movement doesn't trigger the slide in numerous amounts of times?

Comment: Maybe the use of jquery stop()  function can help you